# Напишите функцию, которая удаляет все элементы с заданным значением

Tags: javascript

До второй части задания не дошла, но и в первой не могу найти ошибку.
Помогите её найти.
Напишите функцию, которая удаляет все элементы с заданным значением

var arr = [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 111, 3, 2, 1, "1"];
arr.remove(1); // arr = [2, 4, 3, 4, 111, 3, 2, "1"];

Прикрепите его к объекту массива
* Прочтите о `прототипе` и о том, как прикрепить методы
*
*

```
let arr = [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 111, 3, 2, 1, "1"];

function removeItem (array, value) {
    
    do {
        array.splice(indexOf(value),1);
        } while (indexOf(Value) != -1);
return array;
}
removeItem (arr, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 111, 3, 2, 1, "1"];

function removeItem(array, value) {
  return array.filter(item => item !== value)
}

console.log(removeItem(arr, 1));
console.log(removeItem(arr, 2));
console.log(removeItem(arr, 3));
```

[прототипе](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes#%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2):

```js
Array.prototype.removeItem = function (value) {
  return this.filter(item => item !== value)
}

let arr = [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 111, 3, 2, 1, "1"];
console.log(arr.removeItem(1));
```

Comment: Думала есть проблемы с использованием прототипов и стрелочных функций вместе

Comment: @AliaTempora Не должно быть проблем. Скажите, пожалуйста, если вы обнаружите какие-либо проблемы в коде. И спасибо, что приняли ответ :)

Comment: Да, ты прав. Стрелочная функция не имеет собственного `this`. Итак, внешняя функция: `function (value) { ...` не может быть стрелочной функцией.

Answer (score 5):

Я бы написала функцию для первого задания вот так:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 111, 3, 2, 1, "1"];
function removeAllItems(array, value) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < array.length) {
    if (array[i] === value) {
      array.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return array;
}
console.log(removeAllItems(array,1))
```

Тогда при вызове, например, `console.log(removeAllItems(array,1))` для Вашего массива, получим: `[2,4,3,4,111,3,2,"1"]`, что Вам, насколько я понимаю, и нужно.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 111, 3, 2, 1, "1"]

// Добавить к прототипу можно так
Array.prototype.removeItem = function (v) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
    if (this[i] === v) {
      // так как удаляем элемент сразу откатываем индекс назад
      this.splice(i--, 1)
    }
  }
}

arr.removeItem(1)
console.log(arr)
```